# My equals method in my date class is returning false in my date test program

Tags: java, class, date

I know my two dates are equal because I can use an accessor method to grab the day, month, and year and then print it out all as one date as a string. When I print out both of the dates as strings, they print out as equal. I've tried using several different implementations of strings and dates with the equals method to no avail. I only have a problem when the string that I'm comparing the date with is "1/1/2000". Here are my methods. My toString() method writes the date as a string as "01/01/2000."

The `equals()` method should return false if they are the same date, but one is in long display and the other is in short display, i.e. "January 1, 1990" and "01/01/1990" should return a value of false if compared by the `equals` method. However a dates, such as "1/1/2000" and "01/01/2000" should result in a value of true being returned when compared via the `equals()` method.

This `Date` class was written for the java class that I'm in to get an understanding of how object oriented programs and their classes work.

**Default Date Constructor- Date()**

```
    public Date() {
    setDate(2000, 01, 01);
}
```

**Date(String dateStr)**

```
public Date(String dateStr) {
    setDate(dateStr);
}
```

**setDate(String dateStr)**

```
public void setDate(String dateStr) {
        int slashCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dateStr.length(); i++) {
            if(dateStr.charAt(i) == '/') {
                slashCount++;
            }
        }
        if (slashCount == 2) {
            if (dateStr.indexOf('/') >= 0) {
                int index = dateStr.indexOf('/');
                String dd = dateStr.substring(index+1, dateStr.length());
                if (dd.substring(1, dd.length()).lastIndexOf('/') >= 0 ) {
                    int index2 =  dd.lastIndexOf('/');
                    String yy = dd.substring(index2+1, dd.length());
                    String mm = dateStr.substring(0, index);
                    dd = dd.substring(0, index2);
                    yy = yy.substring(0, yy.length());
                    //System.out.println(mm + "\n" + dd + "\n" + yy );
                    int y = Integer.parseInt(yy);
                    int d = Integer.parseInt(dd);
                    int m = Integer.parseInt(mm);
                    setYear(y);
                    setMonth(m);
                    setDay(d);
                    //System.out.println("get year returns " + getYear());
                    //System.out.println("get month returns " + getMonth());
                    //System.out.println("get day returns " + getDay());
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

**equals(Object other)**

```
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof Date) {
        Date that = (Date) other;
        return this.day == that.day
                && this.month == that.month
                && this.year == that.year;
    } else if (other instanceof String) {
        Date that = new Date((String) other);
        String thatString = that.toString();
        String thisString = this.toString();
        return thatString.equals(thisString);
    }
        return false;
}
```

**toString()**

```
    public String toString() {
    if (isShortDisplay()) {
        return String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year);
    } else {
        return String.format(monthString(month) + " %d, %04d", day, year);
    }
}
```

**Date Test.java**

```
    String date = "1/1/2000";
    Date dstring = new Date(date);
    Date d1 = new Date();
    System.out.println(d1);
    if (!(d1.toString().equals("1/1/2000"))) {
        System.out.println("Error 1");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("This day (d1) day = " + d1.getDay());
        System.out.println("This month (d1) month = " + d1.getMonth());
        System.out.println("This year (d1) year = " + d1.getYear());
        System.out.println("This date (d1) string = " + d1.toString());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("That (dstring) day = " + dstring.getDay());
        System.out.println("That (dstring) month = " + dstring.getMonth());
        System.out.println("That (dstring) year = " + dstring.getYear());
        System.out.println("That date (dstring) string = " + dstring.toString());
        System.out.println(d1.toString().equals(dstring.toString()));
        System.out.println(d1.equals(date));
        System.out.println(d1.toString().toString());

        System.out.println(d1.toString());
        System.out.println(dstring);

    }
```

**DateTest.java Console**

```
01/01/2000
Error 1

This day (d1) day = 1
This month (d1) month = 1
This year (d1) year = 2000
This date (d1) string = 01/01/2000

That (dstring) day = 1
That (dstring) month = 1
That (dstring) year = 2000
That date (dstring) string = 01/01/2000
true
true
01/01/2000
01/01/2000
01/01/2000
```

Comment: What happens when one date is `isShortDisplay` and the format isn't?

Comment: Seems to work for me, can you provide an actually [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry overlooked that. When one date `isShortDisplay()`, returns a string of the date in the form of `MM/DD/YYYY`. If not `isShortDisplay()`, then the date is returned as a string in the format of `Month DD, YYYY`, where month is the word value of the month instead of the numeric.

Comment: Yes, but what if `Date#isShortDate` and I pass a `String` value of "Month DD, YYYY"?  You're `equals` method will return `false`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry I also forgot to say that the value of `shortDisplay`, which is returned in `isShortDisplay()` to determine the format of the date, isn't supposed to be considered within the `equals()` method. And because of that I'm only worrying about why it's not returning true for dates that are the same when they are both in short display format

Comment: But it is...`String thisString = this.toString();`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry I meant that it shouldn't be considered as true when compared with a short display formatted version of the same date.

Comment: At this point I have to ask why in [God's name](http://www.venganza.org/) would you write your own Date class, when you can use java.util.Date or [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?

Comment: Okay, but still can't duplicate your problem...seems to work okay for me...

Comment: @StephenP I'm doing this for my class that I'm in. It's to help me with understanding how object oriented programs work and getting the general flow for them.

Comment: @cbenn95 I think you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @MadProgrammer for your 2nd date that is being compared to the first, are you using "1/1/2000" or something similar to that? Because if my 2nd date = "01/01/2000" and my first date = "1/1/2000", then it returns true, but if it's the other way around it returns false.

Comment: Seems to work for me (`Date`) `1/1/2000`.equals(01/01/2000)` and visa-versa

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have something similar to what you just said that works when it's like that, but not whenever it's `01/01/2000.equals(1/1/2000)`

Comment: I've compared `Date` of `01/01/2000` and `1/1/2000` both ways, I've then used each instance of `Date` and compared with the `String` of `01/01/2000` and `1/1/2000` and it all works...

Answer (score 0):

I used the following as a test...

```
Date date1 = new Date("01/01/2000");
Date date2 = new Date("1/1/2000");
System.out.println(date1);
System.out.println(date1.equals(date2));
System.out.println(date2.equals(date1));
System.out.println(date1.equals("1/1/2000"));
System.out.println(date1.equals("01/01/2000"));
System.out.println(date2.equals("1/1/2000"));
System.out.println(date2.equals("01/01/2000"));
```

And I get the following output...

```
01/01/2000
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

So, unless you're willing to provide an actually [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'm not sure what else can be said...

Comment: on your third test, change your code to `System.out.println(date1.toString().equals("1/1/2000");`. The value returned becomes false upon doing that, and that's the problem I'm having. It should be returning true. But because it's comparing two strings, it never looks at the like it would if they were both dates. I believe it returns false because there is a huge difference between the string version of "01/01/2000" and "1/1/2000". What I don't understand is why when I try to view them as 'Date' objects it still returns false.

Comment: ...and why would you expect that to work, the two `String`s are are not the same `"01/01/2000"` is simply not equal to "`1/1/2000`"...

Comment: I think I figured out what my problem was. I know they aren't the same, but the `equals()` method is supposed to return false when they are both string values of dates. I've figured out why it doesn't convert those string values into new strings, and that's because the `equals()` method used when there are two strings present is `boolean java.lang.String.equals(Object anObject)` instead of `boolean Date.equals(Object other)`. In the sample run of DateTest by the teacher, it prints out without an error and the two strings are compared as two Dates and seen to be equal.